# 1:1 relationship. should I create a new table for a single optional value?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, one-to-one, database-normalization

Let's say I have purchases.
Those purchases can be optionally be refunded.

I want to know if a purchase was refunded and what date did that occur.

Should I have a single table for purchases and a column named "refunded_date" that by default is `null` and that will contain the date when refunded?

Or should I create a new table called `refunds` where I have the `purchase_id` and the `refund_date`?

From a Relational Model point of view I learned I should be creating a new table for it, but it will definitely take more disk space and will complicate queries (having to use a LEFT JOIN) and probably even make them slower.

Example one:

```
Purchases
============
id | product | purchase_date | email | license | refund_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    X    |        X      |    X  |    X    |     NULL
2  |    X    |        X      |    X  |    X    |  2020-02-12
```

Case 2:

```
Purchases
============
id | product | purchase_date | email | license
---------------------------------------------- 
1  |    X    |        X      |    X  |    X   
2  |    X    |        X      |    X  |    X    


Refunds
============
id | product_id | date
---------------------------------------------- 
30  |    2      |  2020-02-12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I learned I should be creating a new table for it, but it will definitely take more disk space and will complicate queries

What you learned is incorrect.  The actual answer depends on a number of factors.  But in most databases, a `NULL` date and `NULL` number will still occupy space in the data pages.  So, you are expanding *every* row in the `purchases` table, even those with no returns.  This extra space slows down all processing on the table.

By contrast, the `returns` table would only have values for returns.  Assuming these are few and far between, it might be *much* smaller than the alternative solution.  There is duplication for the primary key, but for sparse data, that will be a small amount of space.

As for the performance of joins.  Both tables would presumably have the same primary key.  `JOIN`s should be quite fast -- although there is some overhead compared to just reading the data in one row.

In addition, *update*s to the purchase rows incur much more overhead than "merely" inserting new rows to either table.  Such updates can slow down queries on the table.

In general, it is better to design the data model that actually represents the data.  Worry about performance when you have a better idea of how the data will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to add to add this as a separate table.

The reason for this is because whilst your current need is just to store a refund date, a future version of your application may want to expand on this with other information for example - refund reason, refund amount, PDF Reciept etc

If further requirements do come further down the line, there is a lot less existing code that can break and have to be re-written.

As you say, it may make queries slightly more complicated at present but to me that would be a price worth paying for saving the pain later down the line. As Gordon said, you are also not having to store a NULL for every non refunded purchase if you create the extra table - you only have to store one row per refund.

If the queries are indexed correctly and written in an optimised way, you should see little difference performance wise

(usual caveats re: size of your data and YMMV apply)